# Varnish for acrylic painting

Tags: painting, preservation, acrylic-paint, varnish

I was using a yellow wood varnish which is readily available in hardware stores to seal my acrylic painting. They are cheap and good varnishes, but the problem with them is that they leave a yellowish shine which changes the original color of my painting. And the yellowish shine increases with time.
Now I am in search of an alternative which is equally good and cheap. I also don't want to spend much on the varnish.

Can anyone suggest a varnish I could use?

Comment: You posted this exact question already and it was closed for a reason. Please improve your question instead of just posting it again. We are an international community and cannot recommend any specific brands or shops. Whatever is available in local stores where I live might not be available where you live or may have a different price etc.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to repost a question after editing it. Thanks for editing the original, though. I will reopen that one.

Comment: Do you have a link the the original or is that closed too? It can be answered without specific product recommendations, starting with: NOT TO USE HARDWARE STORE VARNISH and never expect anything not made for artists to be artist quality and archival!!!!

Comment: Yeah. Not going to vote to reopen but maybe it should be on our front page: **there are artist quality products for a reason, they are archival.** Cheap substitutes are just that and they will not work in the long run. A jar of acrylic varnish is less than 20$, if your art isn't worth that than don't worry about varnishing it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you shouldn't use wood varnish in the first place, which is a product intended for varnishing wood, where discolouration is usually not a big problem (yellowing isn't that obvious when varnishing yellow wood, after all).

**Find a varnish that is intended for varnishing *paintings*, specifically for paintings that are made using acrylics**.
This varnish will likely be more expensive, since it is a more specialized and refined product, but it will also be a lot better for your intended use, and will not yellow (as much - this is dependent on a lot of factors, the most prominent one being exposure to UV radiation).

The bottom line is that with cheaper solutions for varnishing your paintings you will end up paying in quality.

Answer (score 0):

I too can't suggest any specific brand since that may not be available in your area. I suggest look for an acrylic spray varnish in a nearby local store. It's a spray bottle (deodorant size bottle), which is handy and very easy to use.

Comment: What is your affiliation with the link? Posting the same link without additional information in all your current posts raises flags (see also [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)).

Comment: I am a hobby artist and link is to my blog where I have written an article on how to use varnish. There are no affiliate links in the blog, just pure information.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but the question is not asking how to apply varnish, so it seems redundant.