# Can I use Aquadur PU or Camlin Picture Varnish Oil color as a varnish for my acrylic paintings?

Tags: preservation, acrylic-paint, storage, varnish

I have heard of **Aquadur PU** by **Asian Paints** and **Camlin Picture Varnish Oil colors**. Can I use them to seal my acrylic paintings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asian Aquadur PU is a wood varnish, which is something you already asked about [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/varnish-for-acrylic-painting). These products are not made for varnishing paintings, so you can expect yellowing (and other detrimental characteristics).

Camlin Kokuyo Camel Picture Varnish is specifically aimed at varnishing paintings made with oils. [Apparently](https://www.amazon.in/Camlin-Kokuyo-Picture-Varnish-100/product-reviews/B07NJTFRQY/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt_rgt?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1&filterByStar=critical), users experience a slight dilution of paint when used on acrylics, and [others outright denounce it](https://www.amazon.in/Camel-Artist-Picture-Varnish-Off-White/product-reviews/B07DLKKKJR/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt_rgt?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&filterByStar=critical&pageNumber=1) for this use.
I can't find any information on the nature of this product, so cannot comment on it from a more chemical perspective.

I can however suggest to simply get a varnish that is intended for use on acrylic paintings.

Answer (score -1):

Camlin Picture Varnish Spray are meant for both oil and acrylic medium (see [here](https://www.kokuyocamlin.com/product/painting-mediums/picture-varnish-spray-41-168-11.html)). Hence you can use this to seal your painting.

Comment: Hi SanePainter, can you give a source for that claim? I wasn't able to find that information. Also, the application of the varnish is not specifically asked for, but whenever you post a link, please put the information that can be found there and is relevant to the question in your answer. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: Hi, this is the link from the brand itself which claims it. [link](https://www.kokuyocamlin.com/product/painting-mediums/picture-varnish-spray-41-168-11.html)